# GTK3: opening local html file fails with Firefox as default browser in Windows

Tags: c, windows, uri, gtk3, glib

I am compiling a GTK3 program on Windows using MSYS2 (ucrt64), in which I need to open a specific html file with a local path using the default application/browser. I am using `gtk_show_uri_on_window()` (alternatively `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri()` with the same result). I understand that the URI is passed to `gspawn-win64-helper.exe`, which then calls the appropriate program. This works with Internet Explorer or Edge, but fails with Firefox, because the URI gets translated into a Windows path (`file:///C:/path/to/file.html` becomes `C:\path\to\file.html`), which is not understood by Firefox.

Is there any way to pass on the full URI in a way that it is understood by any common web browser?

My code looks like this (I am writing in plain C):

```
{
    MyAppWindow *window = (MyAppWindow *)user_data;
    gchar *filename = NULL;
    gchar *url = NULL;
    const gchar * const *dirs = g_get_system_data_dirs();
    GError *error = NULL;

    while (*dirs != NULL) {
        filename = g_build_filename(*dirs++, "path", "to", "file.html", NULL);
        if (g_file_test(filename, G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS)) {
            url = malloc((strlen(filename) + 9) * sizeof(gchar));
            strcpy(url, "file:///");
            strcat(url, filename);
            gtk_show_uri_on_window(GTK_WINDOW(window), url, GDK_CURRENT_TIME, &error);
            if (error != NULL) {
                fprintf (stderr, "Error: %s\n", error->message);
                g_error_free (error);
            }
            if (url != NULL)
                g_free(url);
            if (filename != NULL)
                g_free(filename);
            break;
        }
    }
```

The error message from Firefox is:

> **The address wasn’t understood**
>
> Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (c) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

The issue does not occur under Linux or macOS, which leads me to conclude that the driver letter (`C:`) is indeed misinterpreted as a protocol after `file:///` is cut from the path.

Edit: I corrected the wrong string length in malloc mentioned in the comment below.

I reproduced the issue on Windows 7 and Windows 10 with current versions of Firefox. When Firefox is open, instead of the error message it tries to search for the path string using the default search engine (Google).

Changing `/`for `\`in the string filename didn't change a thing; in fact, the URI was still exported with slashes.

Comment: Firefox does not use a different call to open a filepath than any other program on Windows. Why do you add an extra `/` to `file://`?

Comment: Off topic: is `malloc((strlen(filename) + 7) ...` correct?  Shouldn't that 7 be a 9 to allow for `file:///` plus the null terminator?

Comment: The string length (+ 7) was wrong, but that is not the cause of the error. The mistake comes from the fact that I had indeed first used ```file://```without the extra ```/```. That doesn't work (``Error: Operation not supported```).

Comment: Some more information: this is definitely not the fault of Firefox, which opens all possible ways of writing a path (```file:///C:/...```, ```C:\...```, ```C:/...```) without issues, so the issue must arise between the call of ```gtk_show_uri_on_window```and executing Firefox. Google Chrome also works as expected, so it seems to be an issue between glib and Firefox.